# Is there an explict expression between $AA^H$ and $vec (A)vec (A)^H$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given a complex matrix $A\in C^{N\times M}$, is there an explict expression between $AA^H$ and $vec(A)vec(A)^H$?

Comment: Perhaps you mean to ask whether there is an explicit **relationship** between $AA^H$ and $\operatorname{vec}(A)\operatorname{vec}(A)^H$

Answer (score 3):

One such relationship is as follows. Define $f:\{1,\dots,M\}\times \{1,\dots,N\} \to \{1,\dots,MN\}$ by
$$
f(i,j) = N(j-1) + i.
$$
If vec denotes the standard [vectorization operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)), then for $1 \leq i,j \leq N$ and $A$ has entries $a_{ij}$ for $1 \leq i \leq M, 1 \leq j \leq N$, then we can write
$$
[A]_{ij} = a_{ij} = \operatorname{vec}(A)_{f(i,j)}.
$$
Thus, we have
$$
[AA^H]_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^M a_{ik} \bar a_{jk} = 
\sum_{k=1}^M \operatorname{vec}(A)_{f(i,k)} \overline{\operatorname{vec}(A)}_{f(j,k)}
\\ = \sum_{k=1}^M [\operatorname{vec}(A)\operatorname{vec}(A)^H]_{f(i,k),f(j,k)}.
$$
If you prefer, this can be expressed very nicely in terms of the [partial trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_trace). For a block matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{
A_{11} & \cdots & A_{1N}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
A_{N1} & \cdots & A_{NN}}
$$
where $A_{ij} \in \Bbb C^{N \times N}$, define
$$
\operatorname{tr}_1(M) = 
A_{11} + \cdots + A_{NN}.
$$
We have
$$
AA^H = \operatorname{tr}_1[\operatorname{vec}(A)\operatorname{vec}(A)^H].
$$

---

In order to prove that the trace formula works in general, it suffices to show that
$$
AB^T = \operatorname{tr}_1[\operatorname{vec}(A)\operatorname{vec}(B)^T]
$$
holds for arbitrary compatible matrices $A,B$. In fact, it suffices to prove that this holds in the case for $A,B$ of rank $1$ since the formula must then hold for the remaining cases by linearity. Suppose that
$$
A = uv^T, \quad B = xy^T.
$$
Note that
$$
\operatorname{vec}(A) = \operatorname{vec}(uv^T) = v \otimes u,
$$
where $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product. From there, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{tr}_1[\operatorname{vec}(A)\operatorname{vec}(B)^T] &= 
\operatorname{tr}_1[(v \otimes u)(y \otimes x)^T]
\\ & = 
\operatorname{tr}_1[(vy)^T\otimes(ux)^T] = (y^Tv) \cdot ux^T.
\end{align}
$$
On the other hand,
$$
\begin{align}
AB^T &= (uv^T)(x^Ty)^T
\\ & = u(v^Ty) x^T
= (v^Ty) \cdot ux^T.
\end{align}
$$
Once we conclude that $AB^T = \operatorname{tr}_1[\operatorname{vec}(A)\operatorname{vec}(B)^T]$ holds in general, the formula in your case follows by setting $B = \overline{A}$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut See my latest edit

Comment: Ah, yes, the sum of diagonal blocks! Very nice.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the idea: $\mathrm{vec}(A)\mathrm{vec}(A)^H$ is an outer product, that contains all the pairwise products of elements of $A$ (with additionally a complex conjugate in the product, but it doesn't matter here). And $AA^H$ is made of sums of such products. If we can find which elements of $\mathrm{vec}(A)\mathrm{vec}(A)^H$ to add, we can find $AA^H$.

I'll change the notation a bit. Let $A\in M_{n,m}(\Bbb C)$ and $M=AA^H$.

Then, denoting the $i$th row of $A$ by $r_i$, we have $M_{i,j}=r_i\cdot r_j$, where the product is the complex dot product.

Because of this, there is an easy relationship between $AA^H$ and $P=\mathrm{vec}(A^T)\mathrm{vec}(A^T)^H$. Note that the effect of $\mathrm{vec}(A)$ is to write all columns of $A$, stacked as a single column vector. The elements of a given column (and not a row) of $A$ are thus stored close to each other in $\mathrm{vec}(A)$. Likewise, the elements of a given *row* of $A$ are thus stored closed to each other in $\mathrm{vec}(A^T)$.

Then, we just have to compute back a sum of some elements of $P$, to find the elements of $AA^H$. Precisely,

$$M_{i,j}=\sum_{k=1}^m P_{k+(i-1)m,\,k+(j-1)m}$$

That is, $M_{i,j}$ is the trace of the $(i,j)$ submatrix block of size $m\times m$.

However, you are not interested in $P$, but instead in $Q=\mathrm{vec}(A)\mathrm{vec}(A)^H$. Quite obviously, the elements of $P$ and $Q$ are the same, but not in the same place. However, you can check the formula is only slightly modified:

$$M_{i,j}=\sum_{k=1}^m Q_{i+(k-1)n,\,j+(k-1)n}$$

$M_{i,j}$ is again the trace of a submatrix of $Q$, but now not a contiguous block.

---

What about the converse? Knowing $AA^H$, is it possible to find $\mathrm{vec}(A)\mathrm{vec}(A)^H$? The solution is not unique: we can see that $AA^H$ is a Gram matrix, and a *vector realization* (i.e., $A$) [is only known up to a unitary transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix#Uniqueness_of_vector_realizations). And a unitary transformation won't preserve the pairwise products found in  $\mathrm{vec}(A)\mathrm{vec}(A)^H$.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To complement previous answers, you can use the following trick.
Denote by $\mathbf{a}_i$ the $i$-th column of matrix $\mathbf{A}$.
It follows that
$$
\mathbf{A} \mathbf{A}^T = \sum \mathbf{a}_i \mathbf{a}_i^T
$$
Using the vectorization operation, you easily see that the $i$th block diagonal matrix is $\mathbf{a}_i \mathbf{a}_i^T$

Thus $\mathbf{A} \mathbf{A}^T$ is basically the sum of diagonal blocks in
$\mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{A}) \mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{A})^T$ as explained before.
The extension to the complex case is easy.